# Could not find an overload 'init' that accept the supplied argument

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

```
        var segmentedControlImages: [AnyObject] = [UIImage(named: "likeIcon"), UIImage(named: "dislikeIcon")];
```

why does this code produce this error? Its really confusing

Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, `UIImage(named:)` returns `Optional`. And `Optional<UIImage>` is not convertible to `AnyObject`.

You can force unwrap them:

```
var segmentedControlImages: [AnyObject] = [
    UIImage(named: "likeIcon")!,
    UIImage(named: "dislikeIcon")!
]
```